# Contact form [with Recaptcha]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a one page site and the contact form doesn't submit or produce a thank you message. After pressing the submit button, the page shows a blank PHP page. I know this has been asked a few times, but I could not find an answer to fix my problem.

After submission, the form is suppose to disappear and a thank you message should appear before the entire overlay disappears. I also, have a google recaptcha on the form. If a user skips the recaptcha validation and submits, the page just refreshes(or directs to the home page). How can I get the error message to appear when this happens? I provided some of the Javascript and PHP code below .

How can I get the thank you message to appear as described above?
Is it redundant to have a thank you message for both Javascript and PHP?

```
HTML:
<form id="contact_form" action="contactform.php" method="POST" role="form">
```

Javascript:

```
$("#overlayform .contentform input[type=submit]").on('submit', function(e){ // Not sure if I need this.
            e.preventDefault();
$('#overlayform input, #overlayform textarea').blur();
if ($('#overlayform .ErrorField').length > 0) {
 return false;
} else {
 $('#overlayForm .contentform input[type=submit]').addClass('submitted').val('Sending...'); //After clicking the submit button the button shows Sending
var name = $('#overlay_name').val();
var name= $('#overlay_name2').val();
var email = $('#overlay_email').val();
var telephone = $('#overlay_telephone').val();
var message = $('#overlay_message').val();


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'contactform.php',
  data: {
    name: name,
    telephone: telephone,
    message: message,

  },
  success: function(returnData) {
    if (returnData == 'Error') {
      //alert('Error');
    } else {
      $('#overlayform .contentform h2').text('Thank you...');
      $('#overlayform .contentform h4').text('second message');
      $('#overlayform .contentform , #overlayform .contentform input[type=submit], #overlayform .contentform .form').fadeOut('fast');

      $('#overlayform').delay(3000).fadeOut();
       $(".homecard").fadeIn();


    }
  },
  error: function(returnData) {

  }
});
return false;
```

}
});

PHP:

```
//Recaptcha privatekey etc.
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                 $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
 if (!$resp->is_valid) {
   // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
   die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.") //This never shows
        "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
 } else {
   echo "Thank you."
 }
$name= $_POST['overlay_name'];
$name2= $_POST['overlay_name2'];
$email= $_POST['overlay-email'];
$telephone = $_POST['overlay-telephone'];
$message= $_POST['overlay_message'];
$to='email address';
$subject= "Jancarus Contact Form:" $_POST['myOpt'];
 $body = "
<br>
<p>The following information was submitted through the contact form on your website:</p>
<p><b>Name</b>: $name $name2<br>
 <b>Email</b>: $email<br>
</p>";

$headers = "From: $name $name2 <$email> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body>$body</body></html>";
if ($_POST['submit']) {
if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {              
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; //Echo doesn't seem to work. I validated the input fields in Javascript.
    } 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $resp) {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
} else {
    echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would remove the captcha system until you have everything else running properly.

Secondly, why are you submitting the form and sending the data via ajax?  Similar to the above comment I would get rid of the ajax handler at least for now.

Third, if you are getting a white screen it is probably because you are getting a PHP error.  Do you have error reporting on? Your php has tons of variables that are undeclared...I'm assuming that you did that somewhere else but I'm not sure.

I would recommend finding a contact form tutorial online and following that.

Comment: The variables are declared in the PHP code. I just didn't post it because I don't think that's the problem. I tried error reporting and nothing happened.